# Konva drawing diagram lines

Tags: javascript, diagram, konvajs

I need to do diagram lines that connects figures like from https://www.draw.io/, using konva. I tried to do it with wave algorithm but is was slow. Have some one any ideas how to do this?

Comment: You need a simple 2 D for-next loop where the outer loop sets the X and the inner sets the Y co-ordinates of line shapes which you set to the required width and colour as required. Also, I edited your question and added the image - if this is not what you meant please add an image of your own, as linking to external sites is an issue if those sites later get taken down.

Comment: Not that, I edited back. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Do you mean connector lines between the shapes ?

Comment: Yes, lines that connects shapes